# Change minute increment on react-native-modal-datetime-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-modal

I am using `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` for a **time picker**. I want to change the **minute** **interval** to be **15 minutes instead of 1 minute**. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/v/7.6.1), there is a property called `minuteInterval` which gets a number (defaults as 1) and can change the interval of the minutes input.

Use it like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DateTimePicker
          minuteInterval={15}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! You answered so fast i cant even accept it yet haha!

Comment: For some reason the prop does seem to work for me. The version linked is an older version. The newer version does not include this prop it seems? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

Comment: They noted that "all the @react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker props are also supported!", So it should work on the newer version as well.